# How do I use less-known Capybara Matcher options?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara

I've been trying to discern what the less-known options for matchers are. This is the outcome of testing and toying with the options I've discovered. There's basically just no documentation on this stuff, so much of it is from trial and error.

- :count

  - Matches only if number is correct
  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :count => 4
- :visible

  - Matches only on visible elements
  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :visible
- :text

  - Matches text inside matched element
  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :text
- :with

  - Matches form fields with a certain value
  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :with => 'Jonas'
- :between

  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :between => '15'
  - Have no idea how this works. Error is completely illogical.
  - actual error message: expected to find field "spaceship" between 1 and 3 times, found 2 matches
- :maximum

  - Ex: page.should have_selector '<#id>', :maximum => '15'
  - Matches if number of fields doesn't go over the specified number (15)
  - :minimum is the opposite of :maximum
- :exact

  - Have no idea what this does :/  I am dissapoint...
- :match

  - Have no idea what this does either, really...
- :wait

  - Have no idea what this does either...
- :type (not working as advertised. depricated?)
- Output from invalid option error:

  - :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait, :checked, :unchecked, :disabled, :with, :type
  - ouput from: page.should have_field 'gears', { :wrench => 'test' }

Relevant Documentation: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When documentation is scarce, your best bet may be to read the code.

For Capybara, this seems a good place to start:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L27

Also, two general notes:

- If you're fortunate enough to be working with a library that has good test coverage, often the specs themselves serve as a kind of poor-man's documentation. (Look for a `spec` or `test` folder.)
- If you discover an un-documented feature, consider submitting a pull request to add to the documentation. Posterity will be grateful. :-)